# JOptionPane not returning correct value

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Arrays are not allowed, the function was working but just returning 0 as if it wasn't counting the correct inputted character, but now its giving me a "string out of range: 3"

This is supposed to run, open a window that asks me to input a string, in this case it's a word, and then another window opens asking me to input another string, in this case it's a letter. It then takes the second string (the letter) and tries to find how many times that letter occurs in the first string (the word).

For example, I compile, then run. After it is run, it opens a window, I input the word cat, then the second window opens and I input the letter A. I get a return window that tells me the letter A appears in the word cat 0 times. That's what WAS happening, now I'm just getting string out of bounds exception string index out of range: 3

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; // Need for JOptionPane

/*
   This program is used to
   get a word and a letter 
   from the user and count 
   and display the number of
   times the letter appears 
   in the word.
*/

public class LetterCounter {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String userInput;
   String userSentence;
   char userChar;
   int charCount = 0;
   int index = 0;

   userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a String: ");
   userSentence = userInput;

   userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Character: ");
   userChar = userInput.charAt(0);

   for(index = 0; index < userSentence.length(); index++);   {
       if(userSentence.charAt( index ) == userChar) {
          charCount++;
       }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, userChar + " is used in "
                                    + userSentence + "  " + charCount +
                                    " time(s).");


    System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Tha's quite unclear. Tell precisely what you're doing (i.e. which input you provide, for example), what you expect to happen, and what happens instead. If you get an exception, post the complete and exact exception stack trace.

Comment: OK, I found the problem. Tell your IDE to format the code for you, and you will see it too. (hint: there's a semicolon that should not be there. Check the syntax of a for loop). Voting to close for typo.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following code block in which you have put a `;` after `for` loop:

```
for(index = 0; index < userSentence.length(); index++);   {
   if(userSentence.charAt( index ) == userChar) {
      charCount++;
   }
}
```

Just remove it as follows and it will work as expected:

```
for (index = 0; index < userSentence.length(); index++) {
    if (userSentence.charAt(index) == userChar) {
        charCount++;
    }
}
```